# How-to retrieve Twitter user_timeline without using Twitter API 1.1

Tags: javascript, twitter

Because of the Twitter API 1.0 retirement as of June 11th 2013, my old script did not work anymore.

How can I get the user_timeline (recent statuses) with the least amount of coding possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use this excellent JavaScript-based solution by [Jason](http://jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/) that avoids using Twitter's API 1.1 altogether and frees you from having to disguise your Website as an app.

I got this solution up and running in a matter of minutes.